# MongoDB querying to filter a single word in one field

Tags: node.js, mongodb

my data:

```
{
caption:hi there #oldhashtag
}
{
caption:hi there #newhashtag
}
```

what i am trying to achieve:

```
{
caption:#oldhashtag
}
{
caption:#newhashtag
}
```

i want to filter only hashtags for my search function. i am using MongoDB when i tried to filter the data it is coming with the full caption. i want only the hashtags to be returned. i am trying to implement a search thing where we can only search with hashtags.i want show some suggestion to users of some hashtags. kindly guide me how to achieve this

Comment: Have you tried some code ? Please add your code, that helps us to help you

Comment: You can use the `$replaceOne` operator.

Comment: @prasad_ bro i don't want to replace any values i want to filter the values in captions field

Comment: @Roberto hi roberto i want to know is there any query in mongodb like we can only get #hashtags from a line

Comment: My approach would be extract all lines that includes any hashtag and then modify the field to remove all except the own hashtag

Comment: What if a single caption has more than one hashtag, what is expected then?